# Alternative to sphinx search on hosted server with no console

Tags: php, mysql, search, hosting, sphinx

I moved from Virpus to inmotionhosting 'power plan'. Lo and behold, there is no console access using that plan, and so I cannot SSH to the server and install/setup sphinx as I had on the virpus server. I am not looking to spend $ extra on the more advance hosting plans.

The search was conducted on approx 20,000 individual blocks of text from approx 1 line to a paragraph each.

I am thinking I have to find a PHP alternative for the advanced search functions i used so much in sphinx?

Mostly mobile devices connect, so some sort of 'copy text to local machine and index locally' solution is out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try Sphinx SaaS http://indexden.com/ they give you free account if you indexing less than 15K docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way is an heavy optimization of your queries to the database: as a plus you can add indexes to the db tables and try to store common queries results in memcached or APC, etc... If installed on the server...

Never tried http://www.sphider.eu/ but could also be a solution.